# Create ringtone with custom mp3 file - not working

Tags: android, uri, alarm

I have a working Alert Receiver etc., and it starts my 'Alarm Screen Activity'.
I want this activity to play an MP3 file from resources as an alarm tone.

Found lots of questions and answers but no working solution :-(

I have my file in: ... MyFirstApp\app\src\main\res\raw folder

The below code is on the onCreate method of my activity:

```
Uri uri_a = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
Uri uri_b = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.myapps.myfirstapp/res/raw/" + R.raw.def_alarm_tone);
ringTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), uri_b);
ringTone.play();
```

If I use uri_a on line 3 - it works and plays the default alarm ringtone.

If I use uri_b - I get no sound - Errors in logs show `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

So, any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong - or alternatives / better solutions???

Also, some suggestions on managing apps alarms/reminders would be nice.

What are the pros/cons of using MediaPlayer for alarms as an alternative?

Comment: Try to include the alarm tone inside the quote marks

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Taylor Courtney - I have tried that - with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was having trouble using URI's because my application ID didn't match my package name in Gradle Script (Module: app) ... as I changed my application name recently.

Fixed that, and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like this?

```
 MediaPlayer BG;

 ....
 BG = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.def_alarm_tone);
    BG.setLooping(false);
    BG.setVolume(100, 100);

  ...
  //whenever you want to use it 
 BG.start();
```

Make sure the file is in the App res/raw directory.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Taylor Courtney.
but I found my problem :-)

Comment: @Peach, plz share the code, I need to set my custom sounds as ringtone, how it be please.